# Footable: change row position in phone screen

Tags: css, mobile, position, responsive, footable

I have a footable as the below:

[image: Desktop View]

The column starts with Status, followed by Title, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, Date.

When switch to mobile new, it also follow the order to show as picture below.

[image]

I want to rearrange column Status and show it after VII column.

I tried by searching online and footable documentation, but seems no similar solution.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="dnn_ctr538_list_gvList" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="Head nodrag nodrop" style="font-weight:normal;">
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 5%; display: table-cell;">Status</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col" style="width:40%;">Title</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">I</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">II</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">III</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">IV</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">V</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">VI</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">VII</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 10%; display: table-cell;">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
        <div style="padding-left: 10px">

        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <div style="padding-left: 10px">
          test
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/L/I/b/q/o/green-check-mark.svg" style="border-width:0px; width:70px; height: 70px;">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/L/I/b/q/o/green-check-mark.svg" style="border-width:0px; width:70px; height: 70px;">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
        11/07/2013
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the code completely, but what about adding two "Status" rows and displaying only one of them at different resolutions?

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/y7sp0k9r/). I used Footable with Bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="dnn_ctr538_list_gvList" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
<tr class="Head nodrag nodrop" style="font-weight:normal;">
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 5%;" class="hide_small">Status</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col" style="width:40%;">Title</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">I</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">II</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">III</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">IV</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">V</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">VI</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 4%; display: table-cell;">VII</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 5%;" class="hide_big">Status</th>
  <th align="center" valign="middle" data-hide="phone" scope="col" style="width: 10%; display: table-cell;">Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px"></div>
  </td>
  <td align="left" valign="middle">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">test</div>
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/L/I/b/q/o/green-check-mark.svg" style="border-width:0px; width:70px; height: 70px;">
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/L/I/b/q/o/green-check-mark.svg" style="border-width:0px; width:70px; height: 70px;">
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">

  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="display: table-cell;">
    11/07/2013
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide_small {display: table-cell;}
.hide_big {display: table-cell;}

@media (min-width: 476px) {
   .hide_small {display: table-cell;}
   .hide_big {display: none;}
}

@media (max-width: 476px) {
   .hide_small {display: none;}
   .hide_big {
       display: table-cell;
    }
```

}